# Possible to incorporate image content OCR metadata in search results?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, search, content

Argument 1: *SCENARIO* I submit a search via Google or Stack Exchange on some topic which I have recently been researching. *I know I saw* a good answer to  my question *somewhere* - but I just can't remember where.  Strangely neither Google, nor Stack Exchange - nor my textually indexed Safari browser history - shows any of the related words that I'm positive were in the context of the material that I had seen.

[image]

[See the following question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349981/547214) which had ultimately been what I was looking for.  However, this poster, whether justified, or not.. had posted (relevant and interesting) image content, and subsequently that information was in no way indexed or queryable.

**My proposed solution is to run a simple OCR routine on posted images and include that metadata in the scope of the question.**

Argument 2: This seems to be a technology / approach [that is implemented elsewhere](http://evernote.com/) and that provides meaningful added value to users.

[image]

**EDIT**
For those *hooing haawing* about the *insane* processing demands that this would require… I setup a quick test suite using [google's open-source Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) on my Mac (`brew install tesseract`) which I encourage you to try at home ;-)

`PNG=/tmp/test.png; TXT=/tmp/text;
curl -L http://links.mrgray.com/ocrtest > $PNG
SECONDS=0; /usr/local/bin/tesseract $PNG $TXT
cat $TXT.txt;
echo "that took approximately $SECONDS second(s)"`

The Image..
[image]

The result…

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica
Certainly theology needs empirical facts and scientiﬁc theoretical
insights. The social scientists offer help. Yet they do not accomplish
what I must now attempt. My main question is where and how the
church must stand to be the witnssing church; that is, what must be
the relation between the culture that is the church (and the larger
Christian and biblical metaculture the church represents) and those
cultures the church indwells, evangelizes, serves? Answering will
require all the resources that Christian theology can bring to bear, and
not a little help from such as Berger and Bellah as well. Already they
have showed us, willy»nilly, that theology is required for the task: they
make such ample (and often skillful) use of it, themselves!

that took approximately 1 second(s)
```

Stack exchange is more than welcome to use my computer to handle any excess CPU-time required(if they want to pay for my cable modem, lol).

Comment: In all honesty, textual content should rather not be part of an image to begin with. We [recently even corrected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141752/how-to-handle-images-containing-text-vs-text) an issue where a user asked a question for which the text was largely contained in an image. I say that is better avoided altogether.

Comment: I agree - and in an ideal world, posters would know not to "trap" vital content within an image.. Alas we live in an imperfect world - and the beauty of technology is that it can make up for some of our more dogged imperfections.

Comment: I imagine that would be quite a significant amount of work for what really should be an edge case, if it shouldn't be stopped altogether.

Comment: You do realize that processing a single image on your dedicated home computer is vastly different than dealing with the sheer volume of images and posts involved in a site like this? This would involve a massive amount of effort for an edge case that we don't really want to encourage anyway.

Comment: @BradLarson I guess that's a rhetorical question, but _Yes_?  How many then?  10 per second? 100 per second?  I doubt that many.. but whatever the amount it would not be more than a blip on the computational radar, overall.  It's a single transaction, that could be scheduled off-peak, if that's really the objection..  and since when is requiring effort a reason not to do something.. if the result would provide more, and more accurate search results, help integrate and understanding user-contributed content, and generate no-hands metadata? Edge case?  See response to dmckee.

Comment: @alexgray - Well, we're at 10.4 million total questions and answers on SO, although I can't find an easy way to query for the number of those that contain images. The Stack Exchange developers are already incredibly busy with adding features and helping the system to scale, and every feature they add takes time, is a potential source of bugs, and has to be maintained going forward. There is only a finite amount of developer time available, and as Bill says this is better solved by the community in that we should add the appropriate text ourselves instead of relying on images.

Answer (score 17):

I vote against.  Textual content should be posted in text for exactly this reason, and way upwards of 99% of the time it is.  Indexing text in images would be a lot of extra processing for very little benefit, and it would just encourage people to behave in a way we don't want.

Comment: Don't _tell them_ - just DO it!  The court system, police departments, jails, and halfway houses don't exist for the _encouragement of criminals_, but they do help with the problem…

Comment: @alexgray Bad analogy.  The criminal justice system doesn't make it easier for someone to be a criminal either, it makes it harder.

Comment: The criminal, in this case is not the user – _everyone_ is allowed, rightfully to upload photos. **The crime / victim** here is that this data-focused ecosystem is yet to tap a rich, untapped source of info.. that is now only accessible only via direct, physical access. Enabling a way for the backend systems to provide greater detail about uploaded content is **not** going to cause people to all start rendering their posts as images and uploading them..  It will be the "cop" that stops that information from disappearing into a void.

Comment: @alexgray Overextending a bad analogy doesn't make it better.

Comment: I never get all the negativity on `meta` - so here's another analogy.. :) _There's a worldwide pandemic_ - that despite grave warnings - people thoughtlessly retransmit, suffer, and die from. **Although incurable, there is a medicine that eliminates all symptoms**. Alas, the zombied masses refuse treatment - as the disease makes them stupid - and aid workers are too scared/lazy to succeed with vaccinations. This idea - is that same medicine -  administered like fluoride, via drinking water. Disease latent in us all, but humanity saved. Oh, and snarkiness isn't a reason it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a lot of processing for a rare use case.

It be nice in a perfect world, but low, *low* priority.

Comment: I wouldn't consider _photo posting_ to be an edge case use.. and with new sites popping up all the time, i.e. photography, graphic-design, etc…  I would say it may be time to start to at least _think about_ having this kind of feature.. even if it's not "user-facing"

Comment: Posting a image *with text* that represents *important search terms* that are *not to be found in the accompanying text*. Yeah, its a rare case.

Comment: Not going to _say you're wrong_ on something that's a: subjective and b: impossible to know for sure without "official" site stats.. but to see, I [went to the apple SE site and opened the first question with a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57611/disappearing-alerts-notification-center-not-working-as-per-preference-setting) and imagined what additional, relevant, and easily OCR'd info could have been gleaned.  the answer.  **a lot.**